Progress Bar Based on % Towards Goal
I'm trying to make a progress bar that updates and shows how close the player is to being able to purchase an upgrade.
Apologizes if this is not formatted properly! First post.
Here's what I have so far:
HTML:
<!-- Progress Bar -->
<div id="Progress">
  <div id="progressBar">1%</div>
</div>

CSS:
/* Progress Bar */
#Progress {
  width: 100%;    
  background-color: black;
}

#progressBar {
  width: 1%;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: purple;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 40px;
  color: white;
}

What would I put for my JavaScript? I've tried along these lines:
document.getElementById("progressBar").style.width = (gameData.gems / gameData.prestigeMultiCost)

I'm aware that's wrong and a mash up of a few concepts but I'm stumped on how to make this work.
Thanks!
EDIT: Here's my latest batch of code. The goal is to make the background color go from white to a deep gold as you collect more diamonds, up to 1,000.
window.setInterval(function () {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = " rgb (255, " + (255 - (gameData.diamonds * 0.039)) + ", " + (255 - (gameData.diamonds * 0.255)) + ")"
}, 10)

EDIT 2: I just had an extra space... I did it though!

What's gameData? We can't run your code because you have not provided that variable.

Think about the value you get when you evaluate (gameData.gems / gameData.prestigeMultiCost) vs what the CSS width requires.

In this line .style.width = (gameData.gems / gameData.prestigeMultiCost) you need to add +"%" at the end.

Is the question still about setting that width - ie the color changing is not relevant - or has the question switched to color changing? If it's still about width then if gameData.gems is a number representing the number of gems and you are aiming for 1000 then you can set width as a percentage: gameData.gems/10 + '%', However, you need to explain where that cost comes into things.

I just made this snippet to show a different way to achieve what you want.


let progress = 0;

setInterval
(
  () =>
  {
    progress+= 0.3;
    
    progressBar.value = ++progress;
    
    progressValue.textContent = Math.round( progress > 100 ? 100 : progress ) + '%';
    
    // Just give some more time and let the progress reset
    if ( progress > 130 )
    {
      progress = -1;
    }
  },
  30
);
#progressValue
{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 3em;
  height: 50px;
  
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #555;
}

#progressBar
{
  --background: black;
  --optimum: gold;
  --high: darkorange;
  --low: red;
  
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
}

// webkit
#progressBar::-webkit-meter-bar {
  background: var(--background);
}
#progressBar::-webkit-meter-even-less-good-value {
  background: var(--low);
}
#progressBar::-webkit-meter-suboptimum-value {
  background: var(--high);
}
#progressBar::-webkit-meter-optimum-value {
  background: var(--optimum);
}

// mozilla
#progressBar:-moz-meter-sub-sub-optimum::-moz-meter-bar {
  background: var(--low);
}
#progressBar:-moz-meter-sub-optimum::-moz-meter-bar {
  background: var(--high);
}
#progressBar:-moz-meter-optimum::-moz-meter-bar {
  background: var(--optimum);
}
<meter
  id="progressBar"
  value="0"
  min="0"
  low="50"
  high="90"
  max="100"
  optimum="100"
></meter>
<span id="progressValue">%</span>



